# Having issue to make cdn for fonts, cross-origin issue

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make a cdn for fonts. But it's giving cross-origin error for fonts. Though I am allowing cross-origin.

Here is my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/cdn.example.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name cdn.example.com www.cdn.example.com;

    location / {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }

    location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|wml|swf|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires max;
    }
}
```

Fonts files are in `/var/www/cdn.example.com/public_html/fonts`

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved. It just needs some time to take effect the cross-origin.